# Signature with an image is randomly displayed automatically

Tags: gmail, email-signature

When I setup an Email signature for a client on a Gmail account, the image is not being displayed when I look at it on my own Gmail account, but with other Gmail accounts it works.

I tried different image services, I tried setting it on a unique domain, but it seems completely random. Any ideas why it happens?

On my Gmail I setup "Always display external images".. Images: Always display external images - Learn more Ask before displaying external images

From the Gmail [help files](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en):

[image: WA59365 question example]

Comment: Are you verifying that the image is displaying on other GMAIL accounts through the same computer/browser? Have you verified the HTML is properly formatted? Is this happening on new emails, replies to emails?

Comment: The difference is on different accounts, I checked and it was the same settings. The HTML is properly formatted. This happens on new Emails and replies.
I tested numerous services for that. I could only think it might be Adblock.. but that's almost impossible.